# What has changed among two apparently identical calls?

Tags: powershell

I was looking at the PowerToys Text Extractor, in particular was interested in which languages were installed, and from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/windows/powertoys/text-extractor#supported-languages), I got two PowerShell snippets, that puzzled me with their behaviour: here a copy/paste from my console (Italy localized)

```
PS C:\Users\Carlo> [Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrEngine]::AvailableRecognizerLanguages
Impossibile trovare il tipo [Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrEngine].
In riga:1 car:1
+ [Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrEngine]::AvailableRecognizerLanguages
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrEngine:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

PS C:\Users\Carlo> [Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrEngine, Windows.Foundation, ContentType = WindowsRuntime]

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    OcrEngine                                System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.RuntimeClass


PS C:\Users\Carlo> [System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.RuntimeClass]::AvailableRecognizerLanguages
Impossibile trovare il tipo [System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.RuntimeClass].
In riga:1 car:1
+ [System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.RuntimeClass]::Availab ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Runtime....me.RuntimeClass:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

PS C:\Users\Carlo> [Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrEngine]

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    OcrEngine                                System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.RuntimeClass


PS C:\Users\Carlo> [Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrEngine]::AvailableRecognizerLanguages


DisplayName     : Inglese (Regno Unito)
LanguageTag     : en-GB
NativeName      : English (United Kingdom)
Script          : Latn
LayoutDirection : Ltr
AbbreviatedName : ENG

DisplayName     : Italiano (Italia)
LanguageTag     : it-IT
NativeName      : italiano (Italia)
Script          : Latn
LayoutDirection : Ltr
AbbreviatedName : ITA
```

In the end, exactly what I was expecting, but **why** the first invocation (or maybe query is a more precise technical term) of `[Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrEngine]::AvailableRecognizerLanguages` resulted in an error, but the later (apparently identical) call resulted in the correct information display ?

Comment: Interop Library is a proprietary scripting language that Microsoft developed.  It is used to allow automation of Microsoft Office from other programming languages.  It is very slow and inefficient because all commands are created as text commands.  Windows Media OCR is a dll that is usually installed in the c:\Windows\System32 folder.  The Interop runs because you have office installed.  The OCR probably fails because there are other libraries (dll) that must be installed on machine or some dlls are not compatible (needs updating to a new version).

Comment: @jdweng: I don't have office installed, but the ocr **is** installed, with 2 languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first invocation didn't call

```
[Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrEngine, Windows.Foundation, ContentType = WindowsRuntime]
```

without this line, the command

```
[Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrEngine]::AvailableRecognizerLanguages
```

won't work.

You can reproduce it, by closing your PowerShell.

Comment: Then, the syntax `[Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrEngine, Windows.Foundation, ContentType = WindowsRuntime]` wakes up the runtime ? Could you suggest a documentation page about this feature ? I'm very new to PowerShell...

Comment: I don't know any better documentation then this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/text-extractor (the one you used too)

Comment: But it says here, that you need to run both of the commands, in order to make it work. I mean I didn't do anything, then also read the documentation. :-)

Comment: I'm reading right now, and the help system as well. I find difficult to understand where the syntax `[type?, namespace?, arguments?]` is documented (I used the questionmark on purpose, since each argument has a - possibly - deep meaning I don't know).

Comment: Yes I know what you mean, I also tried my luck to find what it really means and what every "part of the command" does, but I can't find anything about it, I can't believe it, that it is so verbose and undocumented - maybe no one wants to use the PowerShell more then the Microsoft let's us to copy paste...